# Stars and Bars combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

This is my second question on MSE, as my first one had format issues. So apologies for that!

I have a problem here.

> How many ways can you distribute 4 balls into 3 boxes?

I would calculate $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4$ (right?)
But further on, there is a fixed constraint on each of the variables, stating that only a maximum of $2$ is allowed in each box. (non negative allowed).
So I write,  $$y_1 = x_1 - 2, y_2 = x_2 - 2, y_3 = x_3 - 2$$

This gives

> $$x_1 - 2 + x_2 -2 + x_3 -2 = 4-2-2-2$$
>   $$y_1+y_2+y_3 = -2$$

I am stuck there. It gives a negative value, how will I be able to count for it? Please correct me and help if there are any problems!

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $x_i -2$ is only positive if we have **at least** 2 balls per box (which we cannot have for these numbers), which is a different kind of problem.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma okay noted. So it is $$y_i=2-x_i$$ ?

Comment: Indeed, it is. This is positive exactly when we have at most $2$ per box.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma sorry again:) , the constraint is $$x_i <= 2$$ but how does it become $$y_i=2-x_i$$?

Comment: $x_i \le 2$ iff $x_i -2 \le 0$ iff (multiply by $-1$ which reverses the inequality ) $2-x_i \ge 0$.

Comment: Also $x_i \ge 0$ iff $-x_i \le 0$ iff $y_i = 2-x_i \le 2$. But as the new right hand side becomes $2$, any positive solution to that has all $y_i \le 2$ automatically.

Comment: Credits to @drhab who came up with it first.  My first impulse is to go for the generating functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your example is to count the number of solutions $(x_1,x_2, x_3)$ to $$x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = 4 \text{ where } 0 \le x_i \le 2 \text{ for all } i$$

The generating function way to do this is to compute the coefficient of $x^4$ in $(1+x+x^2)^4 = x^6 + 3x^5 + 6x^4 + 7x^3 + 6x^2 + 3x + 1$,
which equals $6$ here.

Another way: count all solutions without maximum restrictions by stars and bars:
this gives $\binom{6}{2} = 15$. There are $3$ trivial ones with one $x_i  =4$, the others $0$, which we subtract and also a few where some $x_i = 3$. (these options are mutually exclusive, and at most one can be equal to $3$) The last problem is equivalent to the remaining two variables summing to $1 = 4-3$, so there are $2$ solutions for fixed $x_i = 3$, and there are $3$ choices for the $x_i$, so $6$ solutions in all have this property. And $15 - 3 - 6 = 6$ agreeing with the first solution.

Comment: Hey again, would it be the same technique for $$x_1+x_2+x_3 = 6$$ where $$x_i<=3$$?

Comment: Yes, setting $y_i = 3-x_i$ will work.

Comment: @user478905 what about $2|2|2$?

Comment: Solving $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 3$ by enumeration, we see there are solutions $(3,0,0)$ in $3$ permutations, which gives $3$ solutions, and also $(1,2,0)$ in $6$ permutations, or $(1,1,1)$ (uniquely), so $10 = 3+6+1$ in total .In terms of the original equation $x_1 +x_2 + x_3 = 6$ these correspond to ball distributions $(0,3,3)$ ($3$ times), $(2,1, 3)$ ($6$ times) or $(2,2,2)$ 1 time.

Comment: yes thank you i made several mistakes of not being accurate!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: For some obscure reason, your later comments didn't show when I was posting. I have now deleted !

Answer (score 3):

For $i=1,2,3$ define $y_i=2-x_i$.

Then you must find for nonnegative integers $y_i$ the number of sums: $$y_1+y_2+y_3=2$$ under the extra condition that $y_i\leq2$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Fortunately that extra condition is automatically satisfied, so here you can use stars and bars without any annoying constraints.

Comment: Indeed $(-x_1) + (-x_2) + (-x_3) = -4$ so adding $6 = 2+ 2+ 2$ to both sides gives $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 2$. Then the stars and bars give $\binom{2+2}{2} = 6$ again. Nice and short. Also $x_i \le 2 \leftrightarrow y_i \ge 0$ and $x_i \ge 0 \leftrightarrow y_i \le 2$. But this is indeed automatic.

Comment: Sorry, how did you get " =2 " ?

Comment: @user478905 I expanded it in the comment.